Pictures not rendering in email when embedding in base64
I am trying to embed some logos in an email; they are not displaying and showing

The picture cannot be displayed".

</v:shapetype><v:shape id="Picture_x0020_5" o:spid="_x0000_s1027" type="#_x0000_t75" style='position:absolute;margin-left:-4.6pt;margin-top:4.3pt;width:140.4pt;height:76.15pt;z-index:251677696;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square;mso-width-percent:0;mso-height-percent:0;mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:0;mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:0;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:text;mso-width-percent:0;mso-height-percent:0;mso-width-relative:margin;mso-height-relative:margin'>
<v:imagedata src="data:image/png;base64,*BASE64_HERE*" o:title="" />
<w:wrap type="topAndBottom"/>
</v:shape><![endif]--><![if !vml]><span style='mso-ignore:vglayout;position:relative;z-index:251677696;left:-6px;top:0px;width:187px;height:102px'><img width=187 height=102 style='width:1.9479in;height:1.0625in' src="data:image/png;base64,*BASE64_HERE*" v:shapes="Picture_x0020_5"></span><![endif]><!--[if gte vml 1]></o:wrapblock><![endif]-->

I am replacing "BASE64_HERE" with my Base64 code.
I tried replacing the BASE64_HERE and that doesn't display anything. When I put a '>' after the second data:image/png;base64,BASE64_HERE" it does render an image but shows the cannot display image above it.
I was expecting it to just simply render the images but think it maybe something to do with vector image code and base64.
